# How to read .rdata file in R

Tags: r, rdata

I have a file poly.rdata. Shall I use

```
df <- load(file="..poly.rdata")
head(df)
```

to load the data? But I can't see the data using head(df).

```
head(df)

[1] "poly.data"
```

Comment: `load` directly loads the data in your global environment. It doesn't return the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just semove the `df <-` in your code.

`load()` will load all the objects contained in the .RData file. This can be multiple variables and dataframes with various names, so you do not need to specify one object name.